# Interface name of router

Tags: python, interface, scapy, packet-sniffers, network-traffic

I want to sniff only the interface of my router to get all the traffic (packets) thats going on my network. How can I find it's interface name ?

Comment: What do you mean by "the interface of my router"?  The name of the interface *on the router itself* that is connected to the same network as your machine?  Or the interface *on your machine* that is connected to the same network as your router?

Comment: Im not sure, the goal is to sniff packets that goes through my router to other computers on it's network but my machine. I've never learned deep into the whole interfaces meanings so I hope you can help..

Answer (score 0):

Install `tcpdump` if you can, then do:

```
[root@B6LEB1 TOOLS]# tcpdump -D
```

then the result will be something like:

```
1.eth0
2.nflog (Linux netfilter log (NFLOG) interface)
3.nfqueue (Linux netfilter queue (NFQUEUE) interface)
4.eth1
5.usbmon1 (USB bus number 1)
6.eth2
7.usbmon2 (USB bus number 2)
8.any (Pseudo-device that captures on all interfaces)
9.lo
```